# Transaction () - Query Builder in laravel 5 throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to make an API using **Transaction()** for making more security for database.

**Code** :

```
    DatabaseName::transaction(function () {

   $CheckExistingData = PostCustomer::select('Mobile')->where('Mobile', $Mobile);

  return $CheckExistingData;
  });
```

**Error** :

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2258:

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::transaction()
```

Share your thoughts!

> PostCustomer is MODEL

**PostCustomer Model**

```
class PostCustomer extends Model
{
protected $table = "Customer";
}
```

"**Customer**" is table name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something like this, try with this code

```
PostCustomer::beginTransaction();
try{
    $result = true;
    PostCustomer::commit();
}catch(Exception $exception)
{
    PostCustomer::rollBack();
    $errormsg = 'Database error!! ' . $exception->getMessage();
    $result = false;
}
```

Transaction method will not work like this : See this https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions.

Either you can use `transaction method` or `you may need to begin a transaction yourself`.

Comment: actually PostCustomer is Model and "Customer" table is using here.

Comment: change `DB` = `PostCustomer`

Comment: Thanks for these info`s @Rishi but getting error when i changed model name to db name :  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DatabaseName' not found

Comment: change `DB` = `PostCustomer` in my answer not vice versa. let me change my ans

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `transaction` method is available in  [Database\Connection](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_transaction) and your model is an instance of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html).

Therefore, `PostCustomer` doesn't have the transaction method. You should call `DB` (that's the facade that gives you access to `Database\Connection` and the `transaction` method.

You should do something like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $CheckExistingData = PostCustomer::select('Mobile')->where('Mobile', $Mobile);
    return $CheckExistingData;
});
```

and import `DB` facade of course.

Also you don't need a `try/catch` expression:

> **Note**: Any exception thrown within the transaction closure will cause the transaction to be rolled back automatically.

PS:
*(only if you're using MySQL)*

Probably using a transaction is not enough:

> A `SELECT` query inside a transaction, in itself, is not properly shielded from `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`.

([source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46459/putting-a-select-statement-in-a-transaction))

Comment: Thanks for these great information, @Ivanka . As per your advice i have changed that model to Database name but getting error like :  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DatabaseName' not found

Comment: @Sunil can you edit your question and include the changes you have made? Sounds like a pretty strange problem you've got there.

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible or not to use Databae Name directly here because every time i have used Model Name only.

Comment: I think the method transaction() is not defined in Query builder. Do you have any idea about how to check this ? Or anywhere i want to include ?