# Laravel - Must be inserted in two tables or otherwise it will fail

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Does Laravel have some kind of functionality to allow me to insert row in `Table-A` but must be inserted in `Table-B` as well otherwise it will fail?

The `Table-B` table is polymorphic relationship.

Comment: I am not really a laravel developer but don't you have Transactions for that?

Comment: @Gogol is right there is transaction in DB facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @C2486 stated in their answer, you should use transactions. However you do not need to use `try` and `catch`. In the [database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) section of the Laravel docs you can see the following example:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);

    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
```

This method will automatically commit for you, and if an exception occurs during execution it will automatically rollback for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`beginTransaction`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) to sure to run all query.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
  // First query
  // Second query
  ..........
  DB::commit();   
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  DB::rollback();
}
```

For model you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001987/2815635)

Comment: That is great. I will have to use try and catch block in many service classes i have created. Is there a way to reduce that? something DRY

Comment: You should be handling your exceptions anyway?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back : In the code suggested above gives more control to you, so it's ok to use like this way.